# Install .INF on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, inf

I have a bunch of Vista-compatible drivers from Sony for my laptop. All the ones that come with installers work just fine. However a large number of them only came with an `.INF` file.

I could right-click and "Install" these in Vista just fine, but Windows 7 just tells me

```
The .INF file you selected does not support this method of installation.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, figured out a way. Just go to Device Manager, find the device with the warning icon, right click and select "Update Driver Software". Select "Browse my computer for driver software". Then browse to the directory containing the drivers and let it search.

This worked for me, although the drivers are known to be compatible with Vista, which definitely helps.